# jQuery 1.6 and 1.7 Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using jQuery 1.6 before. Then, needed a slideshow which works with jQuery 1.7.

Both versions are conflicting on my HTML page. Any solution to avoid the jQuery conflicts would be appreciated in the following  code...

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.noConflict();

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#nav ul').superfish();
            packages_slider();
            testimonials_slider(); 
            set_datepicker();       
            set_select();
            set_captcha(true);
            validation();
            jquery_miscellaneous();
        });
    </script>

    <script src="js/jquery-ui.1.8.16.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/sliders.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/superfish.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/pdate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.datepick.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.selectbox-0.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/miscellaneous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"> </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $.noConflict();

        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('#basic-slider').advancedSlider({width: 1200, 
                                               height: 600, 

                                                }
            });
        });

        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.transition.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.advancedSlider.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use both versions. Just upgrade to <strike>1.7</strike> 1.8.

There are dirty tricks to get this (partially) working, but it's asking for trouble, a lot of maintenance hell, and twice the amount of code to be downloaded to the client. You really don't want to walk that road.

Comment: This, anything that works against 1.6.x will work against newer versions (in most cases). 1.8.1 is out now too, so there's no reason why you should be using 1.6 in the first place.

Comment: Indeed almost everything will work, and for the few things that don't there are (better) alternatives. Those features would have been deprecated a couple of versions ago, so you wouldn't want to keep using them anyway. Keep your code up to date!

Comment: Hello all. I have upgraded to jquery 1.7.2 and removed 1.6 utilisation. Now the slideshow and jquery form are both working with this. thanks for your help. it avoided pulling the hair off to avoid using jquery.noConflict()..

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on how [`$.noConflict()` works](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). The first `$.noConflict()` you call resets the `$` to undefined, meaning the first `$(document).ready()` will error, as `$` is not the function you expect.

If you keep the second `$.noConfict()`, after you've called it you'll have the following;

- `$` will point to jQuery 1.6.4
- `jQuery` will point to jQuery 1.7.2